# SpringBoot complementary configuration file in system directory

Tags: spring, spring-boot, datasource, external, spring-properties

I need some help to consume another .yml file that complement the original one in the application. Then I have a file filled by me(dev) however some configuration(as database infos) should be inserted by our clients.

The one which is in the application(**application.yml**) have general configs, the other on path C:\Users\Public\ **datasource.yml** have:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    platform: postgres
    driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb
    username: foo
    password: bar
```

Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**configure the below annotation at your main configuration class**

```
@PropertySource("classpath:datasource.yml")
```

Comment: I was receiving error because for files outside the project directory (example: C: \ Users \ Public) the extension must be .properties instead yml.